# Are there easier ways to create frontend in desktop apps in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, desktop-application

I am new to python and i have used MFC for C++ apps that have graphical user interface, is there a similarly easy way to create frontend in a python desktop application? I tried looking for options like MFC for python but i couldn't find it

Comment: Checkout PyQt, Tkinter or QML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a lot in python.org wiki: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

I recommend PySide2 or PyQt5 which are based on Qt/C++ or wxPython based on wxWidgets.